Decimal Keyboard Not Showing on Android Emulator with API 35 and Arabic Keyboard Installed
I am using Jetpack Compose and encountering an issue where the decimal keyboard does not appear when using keyboardType = KeyboardType.Decimal. After further testing, I found that this issue occurs only under specific conditions.
Here’s the relevant code snippet
TextField(
value = textValue,
onValueChange = { textValue = it },
keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Decimal,
    imeAction = ImeAction.Done
)

)
What I Found: The issue occurs when:
The device is running on API 35.
An Arabic keyboard is installed on the emulator.
    This happens even if the Arabic keyboard is not set as the default.
The device's language remains English.

What I Expected:
The decimal keyboard should appear when the TextField is focused, regardless of the installed keyboard or device language.
What Actually Happens:
The decimal keyboard does not appear in the above conditions. However:
If I uninstall the Arabic keyboard, the decimal keyboard works correctly.
Using other keyboard types (e.g., KeyboardType.Password) works as expected.
The default keyboard works fine if keyboardType is not specified.

Environment Details:
targetSdkVersion: 35
Tested On:
    Emulator: Android API 35, Pixel 6
    Physical Device: Not tested yet (or provide results if tested).
Compose Version: (provide your Compose version)
Keyboard Setup: Gboard with both English and Arabic keyboards installed.

Troubleshooting Steps:
Removed the Arabic keyboard, and the decimal keyboard worked as expected.
Tested on other APIs (e.g., 34 and below), and the issue does not occur.
Reproduced the issue multiple times with the same setup

I would like to add that I added Arabic (Egypt) as an additional input language on the emulator.
Additionally, I noticed the following behavior:
If I first tap on a TextField that has no keyboardType specified, the keyboard opens.
If I leave the keyboard open and then tap on the TextField with KeyboardType.Decimal, the decimal keyboard appears correctly.
However, if I close the keyboard and then directly tap on the TextField with KeyboardType.Decimal, the keyboard does not appear at all.


Please [edit] your question and list the problematic combinations of targetSdk and device API levels. Also explain if this occurs on the emulator only or also on a physical device and if the keyboard behaves as intended without specifying keyboardType.

Hello Ahmed, I just tested it on emulator API35, and it correctly showed the decimal keyboard. Please add more information like @tyg suggested.

Ahmed, which exact Arabic language are you adding to the keyboard? I just tried adding "Brahui (Arabic)" to the Google Keyboard, and it still works as expected in the emulator, API35.

I would like to add that I added Arabic (Egypt) as an additional input language on the emulator.
Additionally, I noticed the following behavior:
If I first tap on a TextField that has no keyboardType specified, the keyboard opens.
If I leave the keyboard open and then tap on the TextField with KeyboardType.Decimal, the decimal keyboard appears correctly.
However, if I close the keyboard and then directly tap on the TextField with KeyboardType.Decimal, the keyboard does not appear at all.

